# find subscriptions already purchased using restorePurchases in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am using `in_app_purchase: ^1.0.1` in my Flutter app to implement In-App purchases of subscriptions. I have successfully managed to buy a subscription once but when I try to use `restorePurchases()` to get the subscriptions already purchased by the user, I get a list that increases in length every time. It looks like there are duplicate purchases made for the same product which is not possible.

Here is my code.

```
_processIAP() async {
    Stream purchaseUpdated = InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
        print("purchaseDetailsList.length = " + purchaseDetailsList.length.toString());
        purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
        
        print(purchaseDetails.purchaseID + " " + purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase.toString());

        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
            print("Purchase is still pending!");
        } else {
            if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
                print("An error has occurred!");
            } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased || purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
                print("Purchased or restored successfully!");

                await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
                print("Purchase marked as completed");
          }
          if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {

                await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
                print("Purchase marked as completed");
          }
        }
      });
    }, onDone: () {
      print("DONE!");
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      print(error);
    });

    const Set<String> _kIds = <String>{'basic_monthly_apple'};
    final ProductDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(_kIds);
    if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
      print("Some product IDs not found!");
    }

    print("Restoring previous purchases!");
    await InAppPurchase.instance.restorePurchases();

    //PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: products[0]);
    // InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
}
```

In the logs, I get that `purchaseDetailsList` has a length that increases (by 1) every time I try to purchase the subscription after using the `restorePurchases()` method. Each `purchaseDetail` has a unique `purchaseID`. Also, `pendingCompletePurchase` for all `purchaseDetails` is always `true` even though they have been marked as completed.

Logs -

```
Some product IDs not found!
flutter: Restoring previous purchases!
flutter: purchaseDetailsList.length = 6
flutter: 1000000819394740 true
flutter: Purchased or restored successfully!
flutter: 1000000819394741 true
flutter: Purchased or restored successfully!
flutter: 1000000819394742 true
flutter: Purchased or restored successfully!
flutter: 1000000819394743 true
flutter: Purchased or restored successfully!
flutter: 1000000819394744 true
flutter: Purchased or restored successfully!
flutter: 1000000819394745 true
flutter: Purchased or restored successfully!
flutter: Purchase marked as completed
flutter: Purchase marked as completed
flutter: Purchase marked as completed
flutter: Purchase marked as completed
flutter: Purchase marked as completed
flutter: Purchase marked as completed
```

This length 6 keeps on increasing every time I restart the app and try again. Also, I am not allowed to execute `buyNonConsumable` along with `restorePurchases`. It causes an error that indicates something about a pending transaction that needs to be marked as completed.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: ever resolve this?